# How can I show php variable as html?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying this code:

```
<?php $img = get_post_meta($post->ID, "imagenes", $single = true); 
  echo "$img";
  ?>
```

Where `$img= <a href = "https://www.ebmovies.icu/"><img src="https://www.newtvguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/MiamiDMT-drk-purp-cover.jpg"></a>`

But on output, it's showing the element as text, all html come in texts like this: `<a href = "https://www.ebmovies.icu/"><img src="https://www.newtvguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/MiamiDMT-drk-purp-cover.jpg"></a>`It's coming whole html code as text, I want it html output ....... (You can see it here: https://www.ebmovies.icu/dragon-soldiers/

It's not coming in html, I want to show it as image and there will be a link on image. 
So is there any way to output the code as html not just texts?

Comment: You could always try running it through [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: I tried a show page source on the page you gave as a link. There are a lot of errors in there. Might want to check that also.

Comment: Thank you very much it works